# Insert array INTO database gives 'array'

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Simple question for you all here, I think. But I cant get it to work. I know there are a lot of similar answers here on SO. But non of them work for me.

** UPDATE** 
As requested I'm trying to print the array. But this give me some trouble. 
If I use this:

`$function_repeater = get_field('functie'); print_r($function_repeater);`

The output is: `Array ( [0] => 20 ) ?>`

If I use this:

`$a = array (get_field('functie', $value)); print_r ($a);`

I get roughly the same output:

`Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 20 ) )`

If I use this (like the documentation of ACF lists):

```
<?php

$values = get_field('functie');
if($values)
{
  echo '<ul>';

  foreach($values as $value)
  {
    echo '<li>' . $value . '</li>';
  }

  echo '</ul>';
}

// always good to see exactly what you are working with
var_dump($values);

?>
```

I get:

`20 array(1) { [0]=> int(20) }`

---

I have an Advanced Custom Field that creates an array

`$Funct = get_field('functie',$_SESSION['post_id']);`

So when I INSERT this into my database I just says `Array`

```
$conn->query("INSERT INTO DBNAME (Afdeling) VALUES('".$Funct."')");
```

I have tried all sort of things, listed below.

1) `serialized` and `un serialized` did not work.

2) `foreach ($Funct as $k => $v)
$conn->query("INSERT INTO DBNAME (Afdeling) VALUES('".$v."')");`

3) `foreach($responseArray as $row){
        $aValues[] = '("'.get_field('functie',$_SESSION['post_id']).'")';
    }`

4) `$columns = implode(", ",array_keys($Funct));
    $escaped_values = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_values($Funct));
    $values  = implode(", ", $escaped_values);`

All of them did not give me the value in my database. This on the other hand gave me `20` in my database:

```
$array = get_field('functie',$_SESSION['post_id']);
    foreach ($array as $item_id=>$item_qty)
    {
    $conn->query("INSERT INTO DBNAME (Afdeling)
        VALUES('".$item_qty."')");
    }
```

I could really use some help here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why `serialized` method not working ?

Comment: Ok so start by adding an example of the array you are trying to store on the database

Comment: Use implode with comma separate and then insert it into values ().

Comment: Are you reading these comments? Or did you just Ask and Run

Comment: I'm reading the comments... But I also have other stuff to do :)

Comment: Oh, ok. **Well so do we**. Ping us if and when you think you can fit us into your busy schedule

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry... But I'm having some trouble printing the array. It's a Advance custom field from a wordpress plugin.

Comment: As per @RiggsFolly Told please show us your array so we can get idea

Comment: I'm trying to. But It won't work...

Comment: Show us what you are trying and what you have done. Please paste in question your tries and your array.